# Peoplesoft Peoplecode events

Tags: events, peoplesoft

i am new to Peoplesoft software and the PeopleCode programming. I have been doing alot of exercises with PeopleCode. I have a question whereby the record fields events such as FieldDefault and etc etc....

I have made an application whereby user can search and add new value. So in a case where I have Peoplecode in one of the event for example SaveEdit, when I click the save button in both cases of search data or adding new value tab, it points to the same PeopleCode.

Is there any method whereby the code will know when user are searching existing data or adding value or rows in PeopleSoft?

Wont it be conflicting for both cases to point to the same PeopleCode?

Another question:

Hi i have a question regarding the passing of variables between the FieldFormula event and SavePostChange.

I have some values being calculated in the FieldFormula and I want to access it in SavePostChange event as I want to prompt messagebox based on the value being calculated.

I have been using the Global variables to access the variables.

Is there any good way to pass the variables or access to the variables values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of search records, there are a couple of Search-specific events, SearchInit and SearchSave.  SaveEdit is when the record is saving so it shouldn't have a conflict with Searchevents.

Additionally you can place code either in the Record PeopleCode (fires every time someone uses that Record in a Component) or in Component Record PeopleCode (just that component).  Record PeopleCode fires first then Component Record PeopleCode. The Component PeopleCode also has additional events that the record level ones don't, like SavePreChange and SavePostChange.  So once you get the hang who fires when you can get pretty granular control of the various events.

There is actually a pretty good summary in the PeopleBooks [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tpcd/task_PeopleCodeEvents-074aba.html#portletsFrame).

Comment: I see thank you! I have edited my question as I have another question @WalterS

Comment: Can you share the code in the FieldFormula and SavePostChange?  FieldFormula is generally used for functions which are then in turn referenced in other places.  In your case possibly you would Declare a function created in the FieldFormula and in the SavePostChange and just execute the function from there.  Essentially this calcs it again but helps to avoid the Global variable.

Comment: Hi @WalterS I think i get what you mean. Peoplecode is rather more complicated at the start than learning other common languages like Java, C# and ASP.NET. Thanks alot. If there is anything, I will post again and tag ur name. :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question of how to differentiate between adding a new value and working on existing one, I would suggest you to use **%Mode** variable in peoplecode.

When working on **existing value %Mode** takes the value as **"U" ie Update Mode**

```
If %Mode="U" then
/**YOUR CODE**/
End-if;
```

When working on **New value %Mode** takes the value as **"A" ie Add Mode**

```
If %Mode="A" then
/**YOUR CODE**/
End-if;
```